# In a WP_Query can I force the results' is_singular() to be set to false?

Tags: wp-query, templates, archives

I have a custom page template that includes a basic query after the main content. like this:

```
$myPosts = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'contentTypeA', 'contentTypeB' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'order' => 'DESC',
  )
);

if ( $myPosts->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $myPosts->have_posts() ) : $myPosts->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

My problem is that the results think that they are single pages. The template part linked by `get_template_part()` has a condition that if `is_singular()` is true, among many other things, render the title as `<h1>`, otherwise render as `<h2>`.

In my WP_Query feed, all the results are using `<h1>` for titles because `is_singular()` is registering as `true` for the posts.

So, my question is: **is there an argument I can pass to my WP_Query to force the results to think that `is_singular()` is `false`? In other words, to make this output like a standard archive page.**

I have discovered that if I use `if ( is_singular() && in_the_loop() ) :` it sort of does the trick, but I am hoping there is a much simpler solution than adding that to the dozens of template partials I have that rely on `is_singular()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really think the **is_singular()** function of your query *should* be returning **true** for singular but isn't, you can force it to be **true** by setting the public property **is_singular** directly after the query, since that function just returns the value of that property when no **$post_types** parameter is specified:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$the_query->is_singular = true;
```

Or if you need to do so for the main query:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->is_singular = true;
```

I can't speak to the wisdom of whether or not this *should* be done—it probably depends largely on your implementation—but it *can* be done since that property is public.